# Deleting Multiple selected items from table

Tags: cakephp, checkbox, controller

In my table I have a column with a check box for each row.  I want to be able to delete all the selected items.  I found the code from this website and modified it for my own stuff.
[Link](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/05/05/multiple-checkboxes/)

I followed the website's naming convention for the check boxes and it is as follows:

```
<td>  <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('LocalClocks.id.['.$LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'].']', array('value' => $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'])); ?></td>
```

This is the code in my controller for the deleteSelected() function:

```
    public function deleteSelected()
    {
        foreach($this->data['LocalClocks'] as $key => $value)
        {
            if($value != 0)
            {
                $this->LocalClock->del($value);
            }
        }
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
```

This is the code for the actual delete button (just in case it is needed):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink('Delete Selected', array('action' => 'deleteSelected'), array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?')); ?>
```

There are a couple things I think might be the problem:

1. The code was written for an older version of cake, I think the website said 1.3, but I don't know what to update/correct in the existing code to make it work.
2. The delete button is the same as the one on cakephp's website on the blog tutorial. The only change I made was removing the id of the item to delete, because im not deleting a single item but multiple items.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your checkbox input should be something like this

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('LocalClocks.'.$LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'], array(
  'value' => $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'],
  'hiddenField' => false
));
```

This will create a data array that will look like this

```
array(
  'LocalClocks' => array(
    1 => 1,
    42 => 1
  )
);
```

And will omit any unchecked ones from the data array because we're not using the hidden field. Finally, just a couple changes to your action

```
public function deleteSelected()
{
    foreach($this->request->data['LocalClocks'] as $key => $value)
    {
       $this->LocalClock->delete($key);
    }
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

I prefer using `Model::delete()` to `Model::deleteAll()` because it runs the callbacks, where `deleteAll` does not.

Finally, your link will actually be a submit button. This will POST the data to the controller.

```
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

If you want to use ajax, use the [JsHelper](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/js-helper#method-JsHelpersubmit) to submit it instead. The following creates an Ajax submission that updates the dom element `#mytable` with the results of the action (in this case the referer that you redirect to).

```
echo $this->Js->submit('Submit', array(
  'update' => '#mytable'
));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Comment: It should be singular since it's the model. Oh yeah, you need to pass the data, so it should be a form submit button. I'll update the answer in a second.

Comment: I added the following for my delete selected button:

echo $this->Form->create(); 
echo $this->Ajax->submit('Delete Selected', array('url' => array('controller' => 'localClocks', 'action' => 'deleteSelected'), 'update' => 'indexTable'));
echo $this->Form->end();?> -  It now comes up with an error saying undefined index LocalClocks and Invalid Argument supplied for foreach() - So it is now going into the deleteSelected function but it is not able to access the checked items.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: That means it's not POSTing the data, or you're using cake 1.3. If you're on cake 1.3, use `$this->data` instead of `$this->request->data` in the controller action. Also, the Ajax helper is deprecated as of 1.3 and removed in 2.x, so use the JsHelper instead if you can.

Comment: I changed the submit to use JsHelper, I'm pretty sure I am using cake 2.x.  Could it be that my Form->create has no parameters.  I have an edit and an add page that uses Form->create with parameters such as: `$this->Form->create('LocalClock', array('action' => 'edit', 'inputDefaults' => array('label' => false)));` (This is from my edit.ctp). This is starting to get really frustrating, thanks for helping me through this.

Comment: If you were using 2.x, using the Ajax helper in your view would throw an error because it doesn't exist. Use `$this->Form->create(array('action' => 'deleteSelected'))` to go to `deleteSelected`, because by default it submits to the location you landed on (check the form action in the HTML to see). Also, try without ajax first, then add it in later. It may be that you're not echoing the scripts in the layout, who knows. Always try the basic functionality, then enhance with fanciness later.

Comment: Its strange because the way I have it now, with the Js helper submit and the action, it all seems like it should work.  I click on the button and the page reload but the selected item is not deleted.  I will have to revisit this another time.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: If the page reloads, you're probably not writing the js buffer. If it doesn't delete, make sure it's POSTing properly (debug the data in the controller and make sure we're iterating through it right). Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

once you got the list of your checked boxes; rather than using foreach loop to delete your ids one by one try this:

```
$this->Model->deleteAll(array('Model.column' => array($keys)));
```